# File in multiple folders gets deleted with one of the parent folders

Tags: google-drive-api

Lets say I have a `cat.jpg` which has parent references to both `folder1` and `folder2`.

If I move `folder2` into `trash` and then empty the `trash`, the `cat.jpg` file gets deleted completely. So `folder1` becomes empty, and I cannot find the `cat.jpg` file neither by `title` nor `fileId`

Is it an expected behaviour?

Isn't it suppose to delete only the `cat.jpg`'s parent reference to the `folder2` and leave the reference to `folder1`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trash is yet another folder or label. Let's assume you have a file that is under two folders folder1 and folder2. In this setting, the file is shared between folder1 and folder2. Once you delete it from folder1, it starts to be shared between Trash and folder2 and anything that has been deleted from the trash folder is permanently deleted.

tl;dr: It's expected not to see `cat.jpg` anymore.

Comment: How would I delete an unwanted link then? I want the `cat.jpg` to survive in `Folder1` and be removed only from `Folder2`

Comment: Remove the parent reference, instead of trashing.

Comment: I meant from Google Drvie Web UI, actually. Seems to be no easy way to do so :( .. Thanks for you answers though.

Comment: Still feels a bit unexpected. If I `rm` in Unix it would not delete the file from all the locations it has a link from. In windows, if I delete a shortcut it wouldn't delete the original file.